# Run command inside dockerfile containing square brackets

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i want to execute this command inside dockerfile:

```
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

by using:

```
RUN [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

but there is problem with square brackets and i get error when i try to build image from that dockerfile.

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c [ -s \"$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh\" ] && \\. \"$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh\"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Can someone help me with escaping that command?
Thank you!

Comment: Write the command in a file `run.sh` copy it in the Dockerfile, then `RUN chmod +x run.sh` and run the `run.sh` file

Comment: I suspect the syntax error is actually the backslash in `\.`: `.` is normally a special built-in command and you don't need to escape it here.  If this is trying to activate the `nvm` Node version manager, though, it still won't work because the shell environment gets reset after each `RUN` command.  I'd avoid `nvm` and just install the specific version of Node you need in the image, or better, use the `node` image as your base.